# how can i change new password/confirm password by using services module in drupal

Tags: services

I am using services module to consume users account details.

Enabled **user** in `admin->services->resources`.

**URL**: `https://drupal.com/service/user/23`

**method** : `post`

**request body:**
`{
"current_pass":"xyz"
"email":"xyz@gmail.com"
}`

I have updated these two values are successfully,
but how can I change new password and confirm password values.

How to take these values in request body and I have tried like this(new_pass) but failed to update.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://drupal.com/servics/user/9

where 9 is User ID

**Method** : PUT

Pass 'X-CSRF-Token' paramerter with user token value in header.

**Example Call** :

{"uid":"9","current_pass":"guessusername1","pass":"guessusername1xxx","pass1":"guessusername1xxx"}

Comment: it shows ["Access denied for user anonymous"] error

Comment: for change your password you need already been logged in. You need to get X-CSRF-Token and then you need to call this change password.

Comment: i have already logged in,and taken X-CSRF token and entered in header page and entered current_pass and pass,pass1 and click on PUT ,same error got.{ACCESS DENIED}

Comment: you need to post not put

Comment: if click POST 404 error ,could not find controller

Comment: if i click on PUT,password changed successfully,but getting 500 internal server error,base table or view not found.

Comment: sorry need to PUT not POST. I change recently and got 200 ok

Comment: if i click on PUT 500 error got,but password changed successfully.

Comment: Check your server logs @User, a 500 error will leave a proper error message so you can work out what's going wrong

Comment: yes, there may be different error not for user password change service. I think file permission related.

Comment: i checked in logs,but there is no information

Comment: @VimalGoradiya how can i take body filed value in request format,body is a text area,i have tried "body":"this is a body",but not saved these filed value.

Comment: For body you need to pass like "body":{"und":[{"value":"buy miui with 50% off"}]}